# Putting an html letter into a bootstrap div without breaking styles

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Let's say I have this wonderful html email letter. [Gist](https://gist.github.com/grammakov/abbd4fa7c3c10f820571).

And I would like to put it inside an HTML page made with bootstrap. Like this:

```
<div class='col-md-4'>
  <h1>Hello</h1>
</div>

<div class='col-md-8'>
  HERE
</div>
```

If I do it right away, my styles will break. Everything becomes a mess. If I start cutting out styles from the message, it will start losing its colors, font sizes, etc.

Basically, I would like to keep the message intact, but I need the following to be true:

- Message keeps its email styles, not overriding outer document styling
- Outer document keeps its bootstrap styles
- Message fits perfectly into the col-md-8 div, without breaking anything

Is this even possible?

Comment: If you're not against using an iframe it is easy.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use an `iframe` or you can use `php include`.

For the latter, just copy the email body content (content within the `<body>....</body>`) to a new file and name it say, `email.php` (Don't worry. There's only one line of php involved).

Then in your current webpage, add a php `include` line like this:

```
<div class='col-md-4'>
  <h1>Hello</h1>
</div>

<div class='col-md-8'>
  <?php include 'email.php';?>
</div>
```

And then, copy the css in the `<style>....</style>` to a new file, say `email.css' and link the current webpage (not the email.php) to that css.

**N.B.** Just make sure to rename your current webpage from `someName.html` to `someName.php` and also make sure that your `email.php` is in the same directory as the main file and you're good to go.

---

You mentioned that you want the styling of the main webpage and the email webpage to be independent of each other. For that, just wrap your email.php content with a div wrapper like this:

```
<div id="specialStyle">
    <!-- your email content -->
</div>
```

Now for any elements whose id or class is same on both pages, say:

```
#commonName { /* <---- This is the main webpage --> */
    font-size:14px;
}
#commonName { /* <---- This is the email webpage --> */
    font-size:18px;
}
```

Just add `#specialStyle` to the email version like this:

```
#specialStyle #commonName {
    font-size:18px;
}
```